# There are $72$ non-trivial points

Tags: abstract-algebra, integers

We have that

$-2 \sqrt{2} < x < 2 \sqrt{2} \ \ $ : $5$ integers

$-2 \sqrt{2} < y < 2 \sqrt{2} \ \ $ : $5$ integers

$-2 < z < 2 \ \ $ : $3$ integers

To find how many non-trivial points $(x, y, z)$ exist we multiply $5 \cdot 5 \cdot 3$ and substract $1$, which is the case $(0, 0, 0)$, or not??

Then the result is $74$, but in my notes I have that there are $72$ cases... How do we get this result??

**EDIT:**

We have shown that the equation $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=0$ has a non-trivial solution in $\mathbb{Q}$.

According to J.W.cassels, there is always a rational (here integer) solution $(x_0, y_0, z_0) \in \mathbb{Z}^3 \setminus \{(0, 0, 0)\}$ such that $|a|x_0^2+|b|y_0^2+|c|z_0^2 < 4 |abc|$.

The inequality defines an ellipsoid in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the number of $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{Z}^3$ is finite.

At the example $$x^2+y^2-2z^2=0$$ from Cassels theorem we have that there is a (integer) solution in the ellipsoid $$x^2+y^2+2z^2<4| 1 \cdot 1 \cdot (-2)|=8 \\ \Rightarrow \left ( \frac{x}{2\sqrt{2}} \right )^2+\left( \frac{y}{2\sqrt{2}}\right )^2+\left ( \frac{z}{2}\right )^2<1$$

$-2 \sqrt{2} < x < 2 \sqrt{2} \ \ $ : $5$ integers

$-2 \sqrt{2} < y < 2 \sqrt{2} \ \ $ : $5$ integers

$-2 < z < 2 \ \ $ : $3$ integers

$$\Rightarrow 72 \text{ cases } $$

Also at the part :

According to J.W.cassels, there is always a rational (here integer) solution $(x_0, y_0, z_0) \in \mathbb{Z}^3 \setminus \{(0, 0, 0)\}$ such that $|a|x_0^2+|b|y_0^2+|c|z_0^2 < 4 |abc|$.

why does there exist an integer solution?? We have shown that there is a rational solution..

Comment: The meaning of *non-trivial* may depend on the context. It is possible that here the author means that the pair $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$. Then there would be 24 pairs $(x,y)$ combined with three possible choices for $z$. It is impossible to say much more without more context.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I added some information at my initial post...

Comment: Mary, the extra context does clarify this considerably. But it raises the question: why do you care whether it is 72 or 74? You are looking for an integer solution, and the number of combination is just an upper bound to the size of the set of possibilities that you need to check out. The exact bound is not very interesting from the point of view of actually finding a non-trivial solution, no? Mind you, my guess is that whoever derived the number 72 lumped together the choices for variables with positive coefficients (here $x$ and $y$) and went from there.

Comment: (cont'd) After all, if $x=y=0$, then from $x^2+y^2=2z^2$ it immediately follows that $z=0$. Similarly if $z=0$, then we must have $x=y=0$, so actually there are only two choices for $z$. This cuts down the size of the search space to $24\cdot2=48$. There are also several symmetries allowing for a further reduction. But my main point is that the actual size of the search space is of little consequence (given that we have a description of it, and know that it is manageably small for pencil & paper work).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ahaa... Ok... According to J.W.cassels, there is always a rational (here integer) solution $(x_0, y_0, z_0) \in \mathbb{Z}^3 \setminus \{(0, 0, 0)\}$ such that $|a|x_0^2+|b|y_0^2+|c|z_0^2 < 4 |abc|$.  

why does there exist an integer solution?? We have shown that there is a rational solution..